# Background SVG / Div with corner cut-off

Tags: svg

I need to create a shape like the below as a background image. I have been looking at doing this as an svg but can't seem to control the size of the resulting image.

I was hoping someone could possibly point me in the right direction.

Thanks!!

[SVG shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDfeD.png)

Comment: do you have a link/jsfiddle for the code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using svg `clip-path`.

The following CSS will shape the div with the bottom right corner cut off so that you can put any background:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 65%, 54% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 65%, 54% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
```

There are multiple SVG generators online:

- http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/
- http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator